# SQL join some tables

Tags: mysql, hibernate, join

I have this four tables:

`User(userId,username,password)`

`Book(id,title,author,isbn,cost)`

`Orders(orderID,orderDate,userId)` (manyToOne to `User` , oneToMany to `OrderItem`)

`OrderItem(id,quantity,totalPrice,Book_id, order_orderID)` (manyToOne to `Order` , manyToOne to `Book`)

I ma going to retrieve `title` , `cost`, `author` , `orderID` , `Quantity` where `userID=1`

Here is my query:

```
SELECT
  book.title,
  book.cost,
  book.author,
  orders.orderDate,
  orderitem.quantity,
  orderitem.totalPrice
FROM book
  JOIN orderitem ON book.id = orderitem.id
  JOIN orders ON orders.orderID = orderitem.order_orderID WHERE user_id=1;
```

But this query has no result!

Comment: Note that you are doing `inner join` and if no matching data is available in any of the table it will not return any data.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty So what should i do?

Comment: If there are no matching record in associated tables then you may use `left join`

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Since my reputation is less, i can't put picture of my tables.

Comment: Maybe start with strait select from orders to see if you have data, then join your other tables one by one to find your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 SELECT
      book.title,
      book.cost,
      book.author,
      orders.orderDate,
      orderitem.quantity,
      orderitem.totalPrice
    FROM book
      INNER JOIN orderitem ON book.id = orderitem.Book_id
      INNER JOIN orders ON orders.orderID = orderitem.order_orderID 
    WHERE user_id = 1;
```